# Installing RHEL 8.3 results in "Unknown error has occurred"

Tags: rhel, touchpad

I downloaded RHEL 8.3  with developer subscription. I changed BIOS configuration to AHCI after issue of not finding disc during installation, But still I have 2 issues. My touchpad isn't working during setup, I need to plug a mouse. Then in half way during installation output quotes "Unknown error has occurred" . Then I gave quit and removed the RHEL boot option from BIOS and booted into my windows 10 and cleared everything from the partition I created. My laptop configuration:

```
Device name LAPTOP-9CJP9P4M
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.85 GB usable)
Device ID   4777967C-E72B-4140-86FA-5F0A1FA8A434
Product ID  00327-35854-91092-AAOEM
```

System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor .  What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please report a bug to RHEL developers, here is how to get the [installation logs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1921159#c1). The old bug report is closed due to the missing installation logs.

Comment: @GAD3R I reported the bug and I got the logs,

Comment: @GAD3R If you need the logs, so you can work with ,let me know!

Comment: Please add the link to the bug report. The old issue has been closed because of the missing  logs.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1951973

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug and they are resolving it.As a workaround you can uncheck the " Connect to red hat insights" and start installation.It works.[image] The bug is https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1931069